# How to replace string excluding specific words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
text.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, c => c.toUpperCase());
```

https://regex101.com/r/vD4aGJ/1

This is to implement TitleCase on a string and it works just fine. But now I need to "skip" a certain set of words from being title cased.

How can I modify that regex in order to skip this replace if the words are in the provided list, like (the code below doesn't work, it's just to explain):

```
/(?:^|\s)\S^(of|from)/g
```

That way by typing `from the house of cards` would print `from The House of Cards` instead of the current output `From The House Of Cards`

Thanks!

Comment: It is what I'm using to code, but I guess since it's regex it can be extrapolated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b(?!(?:from|of)\b)[a-z]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WffcsA/1/).
This makes use of a negative lookahead and a non-capturing group where your words to-be-excluded are listed.

---

So in `JS` code this would be

```
text.replace(/\b(?!(?:from|of)\b)[a-z]/g, c => c.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: awesome :) it worked perfectly! you were so fast I still can't accept the answer :D thanks man

Comment: Indeed it is, or at least it should be! :D